# What are some examples of good whiteners?

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing

I'm looking for a whitener to apply to some image data that I'm processing. I've found plenty of information on what whitening is, and how it works, but I'm hard-pressed to find some actual examples of whiteners that I could apply. What are some whiteners that you know of, and what are some potential problems that can occur with them?